# Mobile Pixel Density: multiple image size or serve everyone the high-res image?

Tags: android, mobile, pixel, screen-resolution, ppi

I'm looking at how to make images look good on android and iphone devices with high pixel density, and I keep running across two ways to do it - one is to have separate stylesheets that serve up bigger images for hdpi phones, and scales down in the css to the right size.

The other is a suggestion that you serve everyone the hdpi image and scale down, and people with low res phones will still see a nice looking picture, they're just downloading more than they need to.

It seems like maintaining 3 different stylesheets (low, medium, high) is a huge waste of time so I'm leaning towards the latter. Is there any reason not too?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of maintaining 3 different stylesheets, you could use SASS/LESS to add some logic to your CSS files and automate the process and use some server side solution to simply swap out path depending on detection.